# Can MudBlazor and Telerik UI for Blazor co-exist in the same Blazor Server app?

Tags: telerik, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a Blazor Server app (.net 7.0) that currently uses MudBlazor. There are things that Telerik does better, but I'd like to avoid a full-scale replacement effort. Is it possible (or wise) to add Telerik for specific components, and avoid transitioning the entire app? And if you know that it is possible because you have done so, any code or advice you could share would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, it is possible and appears to work.

From Telerik engineering:

> In principle there is nothing preventing MudBlazor from being used
> alongside Telerik UI for Blazor in an application. As a small test, I
> added MudBlazor to one of our demo applications and verified that both
> component libraries were functional.
>
> There is only one potentional stumbling block that I identified. Mud
> and Telerik use the same name for some inner classes, so it's possible
> that some references may become ambiguous when both libraries are
> included. The solution is quite simple, you just need to use the full
> object identifier.

I followed [these instructions](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/getting-started/server-blazor) in an existing project that already had MudBlazor. The way *TelerikRootComponent* is used makes it easy to add Telerik without disrupting the existing MudBlazor stuff.